# Tracking java heap without using native code

Tags: java, assembly, bytecode

I was fiddling with Java heap for sometime. Using `JVMTI` , we can keep track of java heap.

But is there any way to achieve the same using pure java ?

I am using java instrumentation and asm framework for class transformation in runtime.

My objective is to keep track of every single object created , which means I need to check their sizes periodically. I can check if new object is created using asm. What I need is to check the sizes of the object created from the heap space.

Any pointers in this regard ?

**edited on 28th December 2013**

Ok , I was able to do something from ASM though it might not be the best possible solution ( best way is `JVMTI` that I completely agree ).

I had to override `visitVarInsn` (for local variables) , `visitFieldInsn` ( for instance  and class variable) and `visitTypeInsn` (for `NEW` and `NEWARRAY` objects getting created )

Every time a new object gets created , I record the object ( *yeah , this is not a good way I know , and this may cause resource leak. If you have any better solution , please tell me . I need it so badly* [:( ] )
And I periodically check the object size.

Can you please provide me with better options ?  (As Stephen has rightly pointed out , this object recording is definitely not going to work , but I am not comfortable with `JVMTI`either [:(]). Also , pardon my ignorance , I could not find suitable `MXBean` methods.

[MemoryMXBean](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/management/MemoryMXBean.html) has `getHeapMemoryUsage()` , but I can not track individual object size from this method. May be I should write my own `MBean` .

Comment: Have you looked at [visualvm](http://visualvm.java.net/)?

Comment: @ElliottFrisch : yes , but I believe it uses JVMTI .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using Instrumentation, you already have access to an API that tells you the object sizes. The very same [`Instrumentation`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/instrument/Instrumentation.html) class that you use to modify the byte code of the classes provides the method [`getObjectSize(Object)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/instrument/Instrumentation.html#getObjectSize%28java.lang.Object%29).

The resource leak you mention regarding your object tracking can be solved easily. Just put the objects into [`WeakReference`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ref/WeakReference.html)s. Then you can use a [`ReferenceQueue`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ref/ReferenceQueue.html) to learn when the object has been garbage collected which is an important feature when you want to track the heap usage.

But I’m not quite sure what you want to achieve exactly.

By the way, as far as I know, JVisualVM does *not* use JVMTI. But JVisualVM does not track every object, either. A full heap analysis requires a heap dump. This can be done using the [`MXBean` with the name `"com.sun.management:type=HotSpotDiagnostic"`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/jre/api/management/extension/com/sun/management/HotSpotDiagnosticMXBean.html) sending the method invocation [`dumpHeap(String outputFile, boolean live)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/jre/api/management/extension/com/sun/management/HotSpotDiagnosticMXBean.html#dumpHeap%28java.lang.String,%20boolean%29).

Comment: Yes I am using the `getObjectSize(Object)` method and then I am using reflection for traversing through the object to get its actual size. Okk.. I am gonna try the `ReferenceQueue` thing and update you accordingly.

Comment: I just want to track the object sizes , that's it. :-) Yes , I could do it using taking heap dump , but I guess taking too many (and frequent ) heap dump might be expensive for the application

Comment: Please correct me if I am wrong. If I put the objects in `WeakHashMap` , and put them as keys , then jvm itself will check for weak references and remove the entries from map whenever an object is garbage collected.

Comment: That’s correct. But you have to take care that the value must not reference the keys, neither directly nor indirectly, as otherwise the keys will never get collected. `WeakHashMap` uses `WeakReference`s for the keys and a `ReferenceQueue` internally so if you want a `HashMap` semantic, it is the way to go. But there’s a catch: it does not have [`IdentityHashMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/IdentityHashMap.html) semantic.

Answer (score 3):

I guess you could do it in theory.  The (shallow) size of an object is easy to calculate from the number and type of the object's fields, and you could use the ASM instrumentation to insert code into to each constructor to record the size (somewhere) each time an object is constructed.

Dealing with arrays would be tricky.  Array allocation doesn't entail a constructor, so you would need to instrument all of the places where arrays are created.  Since some of those places could be in native code, it is hard to see how you would do this.

Another tricky case would be dealing with things that create objects without calling their constructors; e.g. Object Serialization and native cloning.

So all in all, this is probably NOT a practical approach.

---

The other point is that anything that uses ASM and similar stuff is *arguably* not "Pure Java" ... unless the usage is actually part of the JVM itself.

Comment: I am using `visitTypeInsn` for tracking object instantiation. But , after the object is created , how can I deal with it ? I need to have the object list stored in some collection object , right ?

Comment: You should just record the objects' sizes in your stats.  If you start recording the objects themselves, you are liable to create a massive storage leak.  But like I said, I don't think this approach is practical.  You will get more accurate results with fewer problems using JVMTI.  (What is your problem with using it??)

Comment: It should also be pointed out that this kind of memory-use calculation inside the JVM is for entertainment -- I mean **estimate** -- purposes only.  If you want to see useful memory use statistics, use JMX.  When you throw in things like compressed OOPs and escape analysis, you really can't reliably determine how much _heap_ an object is going to take up.

Comment: @CharlesForsythe : Actually , one of my key requirement is to be backward compatible to JDK 1.5 . And I had checked with various `MXBean`s.  `MemoryMXBean` , `MemoryPoolMXBean` , `MemoryManagerMXBean` give useful information regarding heap , but I can not track any particular object size from them. May be I am missing out something while using JMX. Am I right ?

Comment: @StephenC : Yes , I do completely agree with you. Using `JVMTI` would have given me complete picture in a few hiccups. But , to be honest , I don't feel comfortable in `JVMTI` . If nothing can be done in java perspective , then I would have no choice but to move to JVMTI.

Comment: @Coolcoder : You can't track any particular object size with the JMX information.  What I was saying is that you can only estimate the memory footprint of a specific object, and you may end up being completely wrong for several reasons.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `Runtime` class

```
    long MEGABYTE = 1024L * 1024L;
    Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
    runtime.gc();
    System.out.println("Total Memory : " + runtime.totalMemory()/MEGABYTE);
    System.out.println("Used Memory  : " + (runtime.totalMemory() - runtime.freeMemory()) / MEGABYTE);
    System.out.println("Free Memory  : " + runtime.freeMemory() / MEGABYTE);
```

Comment: Hi @Ankit , this will give the approximate value based on JVM size. But I want each of the object size from the heap. Not only that , I want to check the number of objects in the heap